# In Dajngo, Class based views does not render HTML in template-Is context missing?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

``I started to work with class based views, but the codes that I've written initially does not render in the template when I use class based views. The data that is in main_c.main_categories.url, main_c.name (see template) simply does not show up when I use class based views.
When I change back to function based views and refresh the page, the HTML code in the template shows up without any problems. Could someone explain what causes this error?
I've read something about context not been found by the template but I don't really understand what it means and how context resolves the issue.

Thanks in advance!`

views.py

```
class MainCategoryDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = MainCategory
    success_url = reverse_lazy("main_category")
    template_name = 'admin_dashboard/categories/maincategory_confirm_delete.html'


class MainCategoryUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = MainCategory
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("main_category")
    template_name = 'admin_dashboard/categories/main_category_edit.html'


class MainCategoryCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MainCategory
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("main_category")
    template_name = 'admin_dashboard/categories/main_category.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MainCategoryCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['main_categories'] = MainCategory.objects.all()
        print(MainCategory.objects.all())
        return context
```

urls.py

```
path('BaitSouq/MainCategory/', views.MainCategoryCreateView.as_view(), name="main_category"),
path('BaitSouq/MainCategory/<int:pk>/Delete/', views.MainCategoryDeleteView.as_view(), name="main_category_delete"),
path('BaitSouq/MainCategory/<int:pk>/Change/', views.MainCategoryUpdateView.as_view(), name="main_category_update"),
```

templates

```
<div class="col-lg-2 d-none d-lg-flex">
    <div class="categories-dropdown-wrap style-2 mt-30">
        <div class="d-flex categori-dropdown-inner" style="font-size: x-small">
            <ul>
                {% for main_c in main_categories %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"> <img
                                src="{{ main_c.main_categories.url }}"
                                alt=""/>{{ main_c.name }}</a>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[This is Template folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E52KB.jpg)

Comment: can you upload a screen of your templates folder

Comment: uploaded please check

Comment: Which template have you shared?

Comment: Template folder. (this is template folder) above

Comment: You have given there 3 different files. I have asked which one you have included into the Question and uses that for loop. It can be showed only for `MainCategoryCreateView` (main_category.html), because only there I see the needed context.

Comment: main_category.html is admin dashboard  file i want  fetching the data  from admin panel and show on main home page where i display all categories

Answer (score 0):

In your template you have:

```
{% for main_c in main_categories %}
    ...
        src="{{ main_c.main_categories.url }}"
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

As you havent't given that model I guess it should be shorter: `{{ main_c.url }}`.

Comment: its not working